# Project change makes qtp to fail

Tags: qtp

We are using 2 or more projects in an application to be opened. For e.g. HT1000 & HT1200 will be opened by the application, objects are the same(or common) for both the projects. Code uses the values in excel framework for running the test cases as parent to identify the child objects for e.g. Window("HT1000").Dialog("parts").Click("OK") but when we just change the parent name in excel framework as "HT1200" the objects for HT1200 are not getting accessed.

How to resolve this? Is it needed to again add the HT1200 project & objects in the object repo of qtp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing any details, all I can say is:

If

```
Window("HT1000").Dialog("parts").Click("OK")
```

is supposed to work for the HT1200 and the HT1000 case, then

- "HT1000" is the logical name of the item in the object  repository
- The item should have    identifying properties which are    insensitive to the difference between    HT1000 and HT1200 BUT currently it    recognizes a match for the HT1000    window only
- If the string HT1000 is    part of the identification property values, then you could simply replcae    the 1200 part of the string property    value with a regular expression    wildcard which "masks out" the    characters that make the difference.
- Otherwise, you'd need to take a closer look at your object identification configuration and the property values of the app's GUI controls.

Show me more, and I'll get more precise. But maybe this helps already.